# Installing PuppyLinux disables my Ubuntu install

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, lubuntu, grub4dos

I had been using Lubuntu on this laptop of mine for quite some time. In order to install Lubuntu I had to use the `--forcepae` command. That is my processor has PAE support but must be force started. Below is the output of `hardware-info` regarding my processor.

```
-Processor-
Name      : Intel(R) Pentium(R) M processor 1.80GHz
Family, model, stepping      : 6, 13, 6 (Pentium III/Pentium III Xeon/Celeron)
Vendor      : Intel
-Configuration-
Cache Size      : 2048kb
Frequency      : 1800.00MHz
BogoMIPS      : 3590.92
Byte Order      : Little Endian
-Features-
FDIV Bug      : no
HLT Bug      : no
F00F Bug      : no
Coma Bug      : no
Has FPU      : yes
-Cache-
Cache information not available
-Capabilities-
fpu      : Floating Point Unit
vme      : Virtual 86 Mode Extension
de      : Debug Extensions - I/O breakpoints
pse      : Page Size Extensions (4MB pages)
tsc      : Time Stamp Counter and RDTSC instruction
msr      : Model Specific Registers
pae      : Physical Address Extensions
mce      : Machine Check Architeture
cx8      : CMPXCHG8 instruction
sep      : Fast System Call (SYSENTER/SYSEXIT)
mtrr      : Memory Type Range Registers
pge      : Page Global Enable
mca      : Machine Check Architecture
cmov      : Conditional Move instruction
clflush      : Cache Line Flush instruction
dts      : Debug Store
acpi      : Thermal Monitor and Software Controlled Clock
mmx      : MMX technology
fxsr      : FXSAVE and FXRSTOR instructions
sse      : SSE instructions
sse2      : SSE2 (WNI) instructions
ss      : Self Snoop
tm      : Thermal Monitor
pbe      : Pending Break Enable
bts      : Branch Trace Store
est      : Enhanced SpeedStep
tm2      : Thermal Monitor 2
```

Now I wanted to install puppylinux on the same system and dual boot both. I downloaded the PAE version of puppylinux but it failed to load informing me that I do not have PAE support. So I downloaded and installed the noPAE version and it ran as expected, after installing puppylinux, I ran GRUB4DOS so that it detects my other Ubuntu installations and I can dual boot.

The thing is that when I select Ubuntu 15.04 from the grub4dos screen at start i get the message that PAE is disabled or non-existant and that I should install the version suitable for my system.

When Ubuntu was installed with forcepae, why did it get disabled with the noPAE install of puppy? Cant I keep both? or am I forced to choose only one?

P.S. I installed this version of PuppyLinux: http://bkhome.org/news/?viewDetailed=00097

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Right, I managed to sort this out. I booted from the Ubuntu Live CD`using the forcepae flag (which I believe enabled the pae on my processor). I then installed and ran boot repair, It repaired GRUB and detected puppy as well.

So now I can use both installations.